# Updating multiple lists of the same data at once with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm building an app that stores user entered expenses into an SQLite Database and displays them in a RecyclerView. My app currently has a view pager with 3 tabs. Each tab switches to a new fragment which pulls up expenses from the SQLite database that were from different time periods, specifically Today, This Week, and All which are displayed into a the RecyclerView. In each list, I can long press an item and delete it which will remove it from the SQLite database and from the current RecyclerView and update the list. Since it's possible that an item from one list will be in the others, I want to implement a way that I can check the lists in the other two fragments for which ever item is deleted and remove it from there was well but I'm having difficulty figuring out the best way to do this.

Now I could easily have the view pager recreate each fragment which would call the database again and create entirely new lists but this is inefficient. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this? Below is my current code:

ExpensePagerAdapter

```
class ExpensePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private String[] tabTitles = {getString(R.string.label_today),
            getString(R.string.label_week), getString(R.string.label_all)};


    ExpensePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ExpenseListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

}
```

ExpenseListFragment

```
public class ExpenseListFragment extends Fragment{
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ExpenseListFragment";
private static final String ARG_TYPE = "viewType";
private RecyclerView rv;
private List<Expense> dayViewExpenses;
private List<LocalDate> weekViewDay;
private List<List<Expense>> weekViewExpenses;
private List<Expense> allExpenses;

public static ExpenseListFragment newInstance(int viewType){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(ARG_TYPE, viewType);
    ExpenseListFragment f = new ExpenseListFragment();
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    return f;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    int viewType = getArguments().getInt(ARG_TYPE);
    switch(viewType) {
        case 0:
            setupDayView();
            break;
        case 1:
            setupWeekView();
            break;
        case 2:
            setUpAllView();
            break;
        default:
    }
    return v;
}

private void setupDayView(){
    dayViewExpenses = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDate currentDate = new LocalDate();
    for (Expense e : ExpenseDb.getInstance(getActivity()).getAllExpenses()) {
        if (currentDate.getMonthOfYear() == e.getMonth()
                && currentDate.getDayOfMonth() == e.getDay() && currentDate.getYear() == e.getYear()) {
            dayViewExpenses.add(e);
        }
    }
    rv.setAdapter(new ExpenseAdapter(getActivity(), dayViewExpenses));
}

private void setupWeekView(){
    weekViewDay = new ArrayList<>();
    weekViewExpenses = new ArrayList<>();
    LocalDate weekStart = new LocalDate().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        LocalDate dayOfWeek = weekStart.plusDays(i);
        weekViewDay.add(dayOfWeek);
        List<Expense> expensesForDay = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Expense expense: ExpenseDb.getInstance(getActivity()).getAllExpenses()) {
            if (expense.getDay() == dayOfWeek.getDayOfMonth() && expense.getMonth() == dayOfWeek.getMonthOfYear()
                    && expense.getYear() == dayOfWeek.getYear()) {
                expensesForDay.add(expense);
            }
        }
        weekViewExpenses.add(expensesForDay);
    }
    rv.setAdapter(new WeekViewAdapter(getActivity(), weekViewDay, weekViewExpenses));
}

private void setUpAllView(){
    allExpenses = ExpenseDb.getInstance(getActivity()).getAllExpenses();
    rv.setAdapter(new ExpenseAdapter(getActivity(), allExpenses));
}
```

}

Any help would be great as I've been struggling to figure out an ideal way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event bus libraries (http://square.github.io/otto/) for this issue. You can't attach bus on ExpenseListFragments and send an object to that fragments at the same time. Recreating adapter is too cost for devices instead of.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm going to look into this and update you on how it goes.